# Does MongoDB have set for data structure?

Tags: mongodb

I have a list of user ids stored in a field of MongoDB collection. Each of the user ids is an UUID. The field is an array. For example,

```
["59cc7562-751b-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002", "66e6f240-751b-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002",
"742df8ea-751b-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002", ............,"6cf6e398-751b-11ed-a1eb-0242ac120002"]
```

Now, if I want to check whether a user id is in the array, i need to do loop through the array until I find the user id or reach the end of the array. This is slow. I wonder if I can use a set to store the user ids instead of an array.

I am using Next.Js in the backend. If I convert the array to a set, that would be even slower than just looping through the array since the conversion takes o(n).

Comment: The natural behavior of the query {field: value} is to return the document if field is an array and value is a scalar that is in the array.

Comment: @vicatcu for example, if the user id exists in the array, return the document? Isn't that also o(n) since it loops through the array field?

Comment: Who knows what mongodb does under the covers... It might index things to make it more efficient than you might basically expect, or you _can_ create an index to be sure of it?

Comment: See [Multikey Index](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/index-multikey/#multikey-indexes): "To index a field that holds an array value, MongoDB **creates an index key for each element in the array**. These multikey indexes support efficient queries against array fields." So, there is no loop over array elements.

Comment: i know that you can index an field of documents in a collection. But can you index each value of an array field of each document in a collection? @WernfriedDomscheit

Comment: What is not clear with my comment? It gives a clear answer.